# AWS iam simulate-principal-policy outputs wrong anser

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cli

I created and attached a policy for a role **MyRole** to create a snapshot, this  is the policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2010-10-10",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateSnapshot",
                "ec2:CreateSnapshots",
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Sid": "CreateSnapshot"
        },
    ]
}
```

However when running:

```
aws --profile my_profile iam simulate-principal-policy --policy-source-arn arn:aws:iam::777777777777:role/MyRole --action-names ec2:CreateSnapshot --resource-arns "arn:aws:ec2:eu-west-1:777777777777:i-6a6aa66aa66aa6666"
```

I get:

```
{
    "EvaluationResults": [
        {
            "EvalActionName": "ec2:CreateSnapshot",
            "EvalResourceName": "arn:aws:ec2:eu-west-1:777777777777:i-6a6aa66aa66aa6666",
            "EvalDecision": "implicitDeny",
            "MatchedStatements": [],
            "MissingContextValues": [],
            "OrganizationsDecisionDetail": {
                "AllowedByOrganizations": false
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I used AWS CLI to create a snapshot on this instance and succeeded.
This contradicts the simulator output which decided that this operation can't be performed

I created the snapshot like this:

```
aws --profile my_profile ec2 create-snapshot --volume-id vol-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx --tag-specifications 'ResourceType=snapshot,Tags=[{Key=MyTag,Value=true}]'
```

what's happening here? why does the simulator return a wrong result

Comment: Can you confirm that while using it over CLI, where you assumed this role (created temporary security credential) ? or you used the CLI as default user or "--profile my_profile"  ? Can you share the CLI command you used to take snapshot ?

Comment: I used the --profile my_profile 
updated the question with the snapshot command

Answer (score 1):

Your Updated CLI command to take snapshot is NOT executed as the `role`(`MyRole`) you created.

Instead its being executed as a user (`--profile my_profile`).

To execute the Snapshot command from CLI as `MyRole` , you first should assume this role and then execute the Command with new credential you receive by assuming this Role

```
aws sts assume-role --role-arn arn:aws:iam::777777777777:role/MyRole --role-session-name SOME_NAME
```

This Give you Something similar to:

```
{
    "Credentials": {
        "AccessKeyId": "XXXX",
        "SecretAccessKey": "XXXX",
        "SessionToken": "XXXX",
        "Expiration": "XXXX"
    }
}
```

You could do

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="XXXX"                                                                                      
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="XXXX"
export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN="XXXX"
```

And then

```
aws ec2 create-snapshot --volume-id vol-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx --tag-specifications 'ResourceType=snapshot,Tags=[{Key=MyTag,Value=true}]'
```

Remember, in the last command dont specify `--profile` . this CLI is executed as `MyRole`

OR you could follow as this document to [Use an IAM role in the AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-role.htmlUsing%20an%20IAM%20role%20in%20the%20AWS%20CLI) - This will Automatically assume the role for you